# Are there any scripts which have more than 127 characters?

Tags: alphabets, unicode

## This is not a question about software or tools. Please don't comment if you think that's what I'm asking about.

Parsing Unicode-encoded text is a major pain for a software developer, so I thought there must be a better way and quickly came up with an extensible way to do it without *too much* overhead (no analysis done yet). The scheme depends on no script having more than 127 characters -- without distinction between upper and lower case characters or any special graphical representation of the same basic character (i.e. all of the different ways to write a character based on context, counts as one character).

So, are there any scripts which have more than 127 characters?

Comment: I strongly suggest browsing [the Unicode book](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode10.0.0/UnicodeStandard-10.0.pdf) (PDF link).  Maybe skim chapters 7~23 first for motivation, then go back to 1~6.  I believe you'll find it to be an interesting read.

Comment: Have you, by any chance, reinvented the idea of [code pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page)?

Comment: Does your scheme support multiple scripts per document?

Comment: @grawity Yes! In fact, I've come up with a way to solve the problem of limiting the script to 127 characters. It was quite simple really.

Comment: @JohannesD No. It's not codepages.

Comment: I appreciate @bioko suggestion. And I'd give you also this quite interresting read: http://utf8everywhere.org/ . Please don't reinvent another "better" standard (relevant xkcd: https://xkcd.com/927/)

Comment: If you *really* want to do this (you're not going to get out of it being a "major pain", and your thing will just be a nonstandard major pain) and you're *really* sure the overhead matters, look into https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr6/ for something that does essentially the same thing as you're proposing, but uses fixed-size unicode blocks for its 128-character "windows" rather than the use of "scripts" you're proposing.

Comment: @Random832 I'm probably *not* going to do anything about it -- I just thought it was curious that it was as easy as it was to make it easy for programmers. The amount of work required to do this right is so massive I wouldn't have a chance just to define the entire set of characters, let alone convince people it would be beneficial to switch.

Comment: "Parsing unicode encoded text is a major pain for a software developer..." Maybe if you're trying to write your own parser but why would you do that? Pretty much every major language has their own Unicode support. Even regular expressions in most languages have a flag to match Unicode characters. You really shouldn't need to write your own parser.

Comment: It's actually not that big of a pain to parse unicode characters, since all this work has been done for you. Check out [this python how-to on unicode](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html). Even if the script you're trying to parse is in a non `utf-8` encoding (`utf-8` is actually pretty simple and error tolerant), I'm sure [the codecs library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html) can come to your rescue. You probably would also find [this joel on software article useful](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positi

Comment: Parsing Unicode encoded text is trivial for a software developer who uses an appropriate parsing library.

Comment: @DavidMoles: "parsing" UTF-8 is trivial even without a library - you can just ignore the issue until you actually need to reason about code points, which in most common software just doesn't happen (and if you want to do trivial manipulations such as splitting over a `.` or `/` it can be done blindly over the byte values). When you need to get down to details of code points, it can be done easily as well (but further manipulations are intrinsically as complex as human languages - even if you have O(1) access to code points, you cannot just e.g. blindly split a line at any of them).

Comment: @Clearer: "Parsing unicode encoded text is a major pain for a software developer" not really, *parsing text* is a major pain because ***there are a lot of different text encodings***, and everyone and their mother tries to interpret stuff as any of (legacy local encoding|latin1|w1252|UTF-8|UTF-16|ASCII|whatever is written in LC_LANG`), which is typically wrong, and there's no reliable way to detect what encoding was really used for a given text file. This in turn is the reason why you can find around documents in mixed encodings, mistakingly doubly encoded & co. that just cannot be recovered.

Comment: @MatteoItalia I'm not saying the situation is any better with any other encoding; unicode is major win over the previous situation on pretty much all accounts. My experience with making sure a new desktop program supports unicode out of the box, just made me think that it would be fairly easy make it a lot easier. It *can* be solved using good software libraries, but unfortunately, no such library exist (or at least, we can't find any) that we can use.

Comment: @OlivierDulac I've read utf8everywhere.org on more than one occasion; the problem as such, is not unicode but more of a tooling issue. The tooling issue does stem from unicode, but it can be solved: it's just that nobody has do so in a manner that actually makes things any easier. ICU is big, complex and the documentation is pretty just a talk over concepts with only a few examples. libunicode isn't suitable for our project because reasons (the company I work with doesn't anything that's licensed with anything that smells of GPL and don't understand the difference between LGPL and GPL).

Comment: @DavidMoles Please point me to one, that's not a major pain to work with.

Comment: Programming languages really aren't on topic here. Perhaps [softwarerecs.se] would be a better site. Or just [so].

Comment: @curiousdannii As I wrote repeatedly, this is not a software question.

Comment: @Clearer Then you should delete everything you added about C++.

Comment: @curiousdannii I added that because people kept talking about software and encoding and all other sorts of stuff that's not really relevant to the question.

Comment: @Clearer The best way to solve that would be to remove all the references to software, not to add more!

Comment: And you definitely shouldn't say "if you know of any, you're welcome to leave a comment." if you want people to stop talking about software. I can't recommend anything, so that's why I said you should visit the [softwarerecs.se] site! Anyways, thanks for the edit :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72921/discussion-between-clearer-and-curiousdannii).

Comment: Strange, as of this moment OP has 127 reputation. I will refrain from up/downvoting him.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Yes, there are.

Most famous is of course the Chinese script with several thousand characters.

For Unicode purposes, Korean also has a lot of characters, because Unicode encodes Korean syllables as one character (and not just the hangul alphabet).

Even the Latin script has surpassed the limit of 127 characters because there are many accented letters (like ä, é, ô, etc.) encoded as single characters, not to mention all those odd additions to the Latin alphabet used for languages where the usual character set wasn't sufficient (e.g. Icelandic Edh and Thorn).

Comment: More data: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366068/whats-the-complete-range-for-chinese-characters-in-unicode, "Unicode currently has 74605 CJK characters." I admit that this is ~3 scripts, but that's far less than 588 scripts.

Comment: Note that you may also argue the Chinese "characters" to be more like "words" or "syllables" of other languages, while the Chinese radicals are more similar to what the westerners call "characters". Though eventually what matters is that it still leads to a similar situation to Korean syllable encoding.

Comment: Native Chinese speaker here `:)` Note on Japanese and Korean: Japanese has many "loan characters" from (Traditional) Chinese, with some of them modified. Korean doesn't have that many characters, maybe only 80+.

Comment: How much could you reduce the number of components in Chinese if you use something like  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_character_description_languages#Ideographic_Description_Sequences (though this is not unambiguous)?

Comment: @awelotta: I'm not really familair with the quoted system, but a lower limit would be 214 radicals + 12 ideographic description characters (226 characters), but in practice probably more characters are needed, not everything in a CJK character resembles a radical.

Answer (score 16):

Chinese, Japanese, Sumerian, Akkadian, Egyptian hieroglyphs, Sanskrit, the list is endless.

Comment: Sanskrit is a language, not a script. Devanagari (the script) has far fewer than 127 distinct characters; the various ligatures are not encoded separately in Unicode.

Comment: @chepner. If we take “charater” to mean akṣara, then you have to count the signs for simple consonants, for consonant clusters, and for either of these followed by a vowel. This will take you well into the hundreds.

Comment: That's what I meant by "ligature"; Unicode doesn't encode them, and leaves it as a problem for the rendering engine to handle.

Comment: @chepner perhaps too philosophical a question, but isn't any script just a set of ligatures for a long string of ones and zeroes?

Comment: @chepner Even if you count Unicode codepoints, there are more than 127 Devanagari characters encoded in Unicode: 128 in the [Devanagari block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devanagari_(Unicode_block)), 30 in the [Devanagari Extended block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devanagari_Extended), and 42 in the [Vedic Extensions block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vedic_Extensions).

Comment: The list is not endless. I would be surprised if it goes over 50 items. Not saying that the answer needs to list all of them, but I think it's inaccurate to call it "endless" by any definition or hyperbole

Comment: I was not aware of Devanagari Extended or Vedic extensions, and I used "far fewer" to refer to just the "alphabetic" characters, ignoring the numbers, punctuation, and miscellaneous symbols (which isn't fair, admittedly).

Comment: @chepner The Vedic extensions is actually used by Sanskrit (namely Vedic Sanskrit), so *technically* it could still surpass 127 codepoints.

Answer (score 9):

For an alphabet used for a single language, Vietnamese has:

- 29 letters (including the vowels without tone marks)
- 12 vowels can accept 5 tone marks each
- All these of course in upper and lower case

For a total of **178 letters**.

The Windows-1258 codepage solves this by implementing the tone marks as combining characters only (except for some of the composed caracters that already existed in Latin-1)

For VISCII, the entire upper half is filled with 128 letters, along with six more that replace C0 control characters (a total of 186 letters are encoded, the 178 mentioned, plus the basic ASCII letters *not* used for Vietnamese).

Comment: But the question says: "without distinction between upper and lower case characters".

Comment: Oops, I missed that (though I have no idea how his encoding scheme is going to avoid distinguishing upper and lowercase characters)

Comment: @Random832 IT'S AN ATTEMPT TO MAKE SURE THAT THINGS ARE COMMUNICATED LOUDLY AND CLEARLY.

Comment: On the first computer to which I was exposed, characters were six bits and the shift code was a separate character, so ‘A’ was encoded as ‘↑a’.

Answer (score 3):

[Tamil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamil_script) is another example; there are 12 vowels and 18 consonants, plus one special character, so the alphabet has 31 (12+18+1) independent letters and 216 (12 * 16) combined letters (consonant + a vowel mark) for a total of 247 letters. The Wikipedia page link has the Unicode tables for the characters.

Comment: But in Unicode, all Indic scripts (including Tamil) are analysed into consonants and vowels (and a virama for vowelessness), saving a lot of characters or code points.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - just wanted the OP to have another interesting alphabet to consider.